# CacheDependency Question Regarding Simulataneous Requests

Tags: asp.net, file, caching, locking, request

I have a quick question; when using cachedependency with an xml file, could a situation occur where two simultaneous requests cause one request to read the file to update the cache, and the other then crashes because the file is being accessed?

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is a serious implementation bug in the CacheDependency code, the first request will lock the file and the other requests will wait until the lock is removed or the state of the cache dependency updated.

This mechanism (CacheDepenendency) is designed for heavy traffic scenarios and I am sure such thing is covered...

Comment: I have been trying to find something that confirms what your saying; however, since I can't find anything, and your point does make sense, you get the answer, thanks!